# Unable to Install PHPMyAdmin on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, php7, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to update all my software on my CentOS 6 Server. I have updated from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2 and now trying to install PHPMyAdmin 4.8 but I am getting an error when running the `yum` command.

`yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install phpMyAdmin`

```
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-2.el6.remi.noarch (remi)
           Requires: php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-zip
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.1.20170219dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-zip = 1:1.14.0-0.1.20170219dev.el6.remi.5.6
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-zip = 1:1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.1-2.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.1-2.el6.remi.7.2
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.2-1.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.2-1.el6.remi.7.2
           Available: php56u-common-5.6.35-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php70u-common-7.0.29-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Installed: php-common-7.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-7.2.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               Not found
Error: Package: composer-1.6.4-1.el6.remi.noarch (remi)
           Requires: php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-zip
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.1.20170219dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-zip = 1:1.14.0-0.1.20170219dev.el6.remi.5.6
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-zip = 1:1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.1-2.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.1-2.el6.remi.7.2
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.2-1.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.2-1.el6.remi.7.2
           Available: php56u-common-5.6.35-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php70u-common-7.0.29-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Installed: php-common-7.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-7.2.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple issues here:

First, the repo `ius` is not compatible with `remi` repositories. Since you are using PHP from remi, you should disable and remove the IUS repo(s) (and find other sources for any *other* packages you might have from IUS).

Second, it looks like your system somehow got connected to an out of date mirror. I would clear the yum caches with `yum clean all` and try again.

Third, you should persistently enable repos you are actually using such as remi and remi-php72 etc. These ship disabled, but if you forget to enable them with each command, you will run into dependency issues.

Finally, you enabled remi-test, the contents of which may be unstable or change at any time. It's likely you've got some bad packages from there, in which case disable it and see:

If this still persists, I would run `yum distro-sync` to ensure that all the installed packages match what is actually available in the repositories.